# Expectation of the sum of two Dirac deltas

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, expected-value, dirac-delta

Let $X_1,X_2$ be random vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with joint PDF $f(x_1,x_2)$ such that $f(x_1,x_2)=f(x_2,x_1)\,\,\, \forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ (i.e. $f$ is *symmetric*).
Consider the following integral
\begin{equation}\mathbb{E}[\delta_{X_1}(x)+\delta_{X_2}(x)]=\iint [\delta_{x_1}(x)+\delta_{x_2}(x)]\,f(x_1,x_2)\text{ d}x_1\text{d}x_2\end{equation}
where $\delta_{x_i}(x)$ is the Dirac delta concentrated in $x_i$. I'm not sure if I have computed correctly such integration. My calculation are the following:
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}[\delta_{X_1}(x)+\delta_{X_2}(x)] &=\iint [\delta_{x_1}(x)+\delta_{x_2}(x)]\,f(x_1,x_2)\text{ d}x_1\text{d}x_2 \\
&=\iint \delta_{x_1}(x)\,f(x_1,x_2)\text{ d}x_1\text{d}x_2+\iint \delta_{x_2}(x)\,f(x_1,x_2)\text{ d}x_1\text{d}x_2 \\
&=\int f(x,x_2)\text{ d}x_2+\int f(x_1,x)\text{ d}x_1 \\
&=2\int f(x,w)\text{ d}w
\end{aligned}\end{equation}
where between the third and the fourth member I've exploited the sampling property of the deltas and between the fourth and the fifth member I've exploited the symmetry of $f$.